# verifying smart contract using etherscan api?

Tags: javascript, contract-verification, api

I wanted to verify my smart contract from polygonscan api but when I use this code I always get a Module Error :

> "Error! Missing Or invalid Module name"

and this is the code I am using in Javascript

```
  async function verifying(name, source, contract) {
    const result = await axios.post(`https://api-testnet.polygonscan.com/api`, {
      apikey: process.env.POLYGON_API_KEY,
      contractaddress: contract,
      codeformat: 'solidity-single-file',
      module: 'contract',
      action: 'verifysourcecode',
      sourceCode: source,
      codeformat: 'solidity',
      contractname: name,
      compilerversion: 'v0.8.17+commit.8df45f5f',
      optimizationUsed: 0,
      runs: 200
    });
    console.log(result.data)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
async function verifying(name, source, contract) {
    const result = await axios.post(`https://api-testnet.polygonscan.com/api`, null, {
      apikey: process.env.POLYGON_API_KEY,
      contractaddress: contract,
      codeformat: 'solidity-single-file',
      module: 'contract',
      action: 'verifysourcecode',
      sourceCode: source,
      codeformat: 'solidity',
      contractname: name,
      compilerversion: 'v0.8.17+commit.8df45f5f',
      optimizationUsed: 0,
      runs: 200
    });
    console.log(result.data)
  }
```